# Wake up mac os x in every hour

Tags: mac, sleep

Is there a way to wake up my mac os x (Ventura 13.0) from sleep mode in every hour? I'd like to run my crypto bot periodically (a python script).
I've already found several ways to wake up my mac every day in a specific time like with `pmset repeat wake` or creating an Automator application and schedule it with icalendar but these are only once in a day.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "`pmset relative wake` *seconds*" will schedule a wake the specified number of seconds after the machine goes to sleep, but that is not tied to a particular "wall clock time", and will drift over time (i.e. it won't keep running precisely at the top of the hour every hour). But it might be enough for your needs…?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm much closer with it then before but for me time is a very important (because market moves fast) so it would be important to run it exactly one 1 hour